# Eric4 calling on a text file

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

How do you call a text file into Eric4? In which directory should I place the file? My small script needs to pull data using python-pandas and when I tried to run this inside Eric4 I get

```
The debugged program raised the exception unhandled IOError
"[Errno  2] No such file or directory: 'blank.txt'"
File: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py, Line 1633

Break here?
```

There wasn't an 'Eric4' tag, so I'm hoping somebody knows something about the program.

Thanks.

EDIT:

**SOLVED**: OP remembered to double-check that the `.txt` file and `.py` file were in the same directory. Eric4 had no problems after that.

Comment: Is that the enture stacktrace? Which part of your code is trying to read blank.txt (could you include that bit?)

Comment: @AndyHayden Yeah, that was the full error that showed up. I fixed the problem...super embarrassing...it was as easy as just making sure to **double check** that my text file was in the same directory as my .py file. Thanks for giving up some of your time.